# What is the error with the update_social_flows_in_older_consequential function when importing ecoinvent 3.6 conseq to brightway?

Tags: brightway

When trying to import ecoinvent in brightway,

```
ei36 = bw2.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(ei36dir, "ecoinvent 3.6 conseq")
ei36.apply_strategies()
ei36.statistics()
ei36.write_database()
```

I get the following error message:

```
*Applying strategy: update_social_flows_in_older_consequential

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\...\test.py", line 24, in <module>
ei36.apply_strategies()

File "C:\Users\...\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\base.py", line 69, in apply_strategies
self.apply_strategy(func, verbose)

File "C:\Users\...\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\base.py", line 48, in apply_strategy
self.data = strategy(self.data)

File "C:\Users\...\Lib\site-packages\bw2io\strategies\ecospold2.py", line 1350, in update_social_flows_in_older_consequential

exc['input'] = cache[exc['name']]

KeyError: 'venting of argon, crude, liquid'*
```

I had a look at the update_social_flows_in_older_consequential function (below), but I can't figure out the problem.

```
def update_social_flows_in_older_consequential(db, biosphere_db):

    FLOWS = {
        'residual wood, dry',
        'venting of argon, crude, liquid',
        'venting of nitrogen, liquid',
    }

    cache = {}

    def get_cache(cache, biosphere_db):
        for flow in biosphere_db:
            if flow['name'] in FLOWS:
                cache[flow['name']] = flow.key

    for ds in db:
        for exc in ds['exchanges']:
            if not exc.get('input') and exc['name'] in FLOWS:
                if not cache:
                    get_cache(cache, biosphere_db)
                exc['input'] = cache[exc['name']]
    return db
```

Is there anybody who encountered a similar issue?

Comment: Can you give more details on how you imported version 3.6? The best way now is to use [import ecoinvent release](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/main/bw2io/ecoinvent.py#L55), which should work without problems.

These social flows (used to) have different UUIDs for each ecoinvent release, and I guess that the flow list you are using disagrees with the values present in 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```py
import bw2data as bd
import bw2io as bi
bd.projects.set_current("CHANGE-ME")
bi.import_ecoinvent_release('3.6', 'consequential')
```

Note that this requires a recent version of bw2io (either BW2 or BW2.5).

Note that you don't need to run `bw2setup()`. The above command will create the correct biosphere database for you. See the [mailing list announcement](https://brightway.groups.io/g/updates/message/36) for more info.

Why do you get an error? The "social" flows in ecoinvent only exist in the consequential version, and as such were created as that system model was executed. That meant that they didn't have a fixed UUID (this has now changed). So in each release there was a new value (i.e. `73dbaeb8-6b92-490d-859c-88e8148c71c4` in 3.6, `845e9acd-5f87-4ebd-8dbd-0a54cfbbd63b` in 3.7), and as `bw2io` matches against the UUID it needed to be updated. `bw2setup()` is hard-coded to a specific release version, and if that didn't agree with the expected migration value you would have errors.